# Bamboo bash script accept input

Tags: bash, bamboo

I have the following bash script, it runs outside of bamboo, but when I put it in a bamboo task it errors out

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(ps -p "$$" -o comm=)" != "bash" ]; then
    bash "$0" "$@"
    exit "$?"
fi

npm adduser --registry https://privaterepo.com/repository/npm-all/ <<!
$bamboo_NPM_USERNAME
$bamboo_NPM_PASSWORD
$bamboo_NPM_EMAIL
!
```

Returns in the log

> npm ERR! cb() never called!
>   Username: Password:

Is there a specific syntax to use inside a bamboo plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The npm client is a crappy piece of software that cant handle headless login, so I just removed it from the equation and used a node login script instead.